# Is Virtual Key Code a hardware & software independent identification of keys?

Tags: input, keyboard, key

I am trying to intercept keyboard actions and identify the keys being pressed. Now I can get the virtual key code. But I am not sure if it is a hardware & software independent identification of keys?

Will they change with different keyboard models? Or different keyboard layouts? Or different operating systems? Are they some kind of standardized IDs for all possible keys?

Answer (score 0):

I am collecting references to here. Hopefully it will finally evolve into an answer. If someone has a better one, please feel free to post it.

[About Keyboard Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): explains concepts like `scan code`, [virtual key code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Virtual_Key_Codes_Described), and `keystroke messages`.